# Sending text to another application

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I am looking to send some text fields from Excel to another application using the SendMessage method. Here is my code below:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As Long, _
     ByRef lParam As Any) As Long
     
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As Long, _
     ByRef lParam As String) As Long
           
Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
     
Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" ( _
     ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
     ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
     ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
     ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Public Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
Public Const BM_CLICK As Long = &HF5&


    Sub RunApplication()
Dim Vendor As String
Dim qty As String
Dim PartId As String


hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Purchase Order Entry - Infor ERP VISUAL Enterprise - LIVE")
gupta_form = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "Gupta:Form", vbNullString)
Order_Date = FindWindowEx(gupta_form, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)
Our_OrderID = FindWindowEx(gupta_form, Order_Date, "Edit", vbNullString)
VendorID = FindWindowEx(gupta_form, Our_OrderID, "Edit", vbNullString)
gupta_dialog = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "Gupta:Dialog", "Table Toolbar")
gupta_child_table = FindWindowEx(gupta_form, 0, "Gupta:ChildTable", vbNullString)
list_clip = FindWindowEx(gupta_child_table, 0, "Gupta:ChildTable:ListClip", vbNullString)
Open_line = FindWindowEx(gupta_dialog, 0, "Button", vbNullString)
qty_edit = FindWindowEx(list_clip, 0, "Edit", vbNullString)

Vendor = Sheets("Daily Stock").Range("H16")
qty = Sheets("Daily Stock").Range("I16")
PartId = Sheets("Daily Stock").Range("A16")


Call SendMessageByString(VendorID, WM_SETTEXT, ByVal CLng(0), ByVal Vendor) 'Enter Vendor ID into Field
Call SendMessageByString(Open_line, BM_CLICK, 0, ByVal 0&) 'Click Button to open Quantity field
Timeout (2) 'Wait until Quantity field is open
Call SendMessageByString(qty_edit, WM_SETTEXT, ByVal CLng(0), ByVal qty) 'Enter Quantity from Daily Stock sheet



End Sub
```

I am having 2 problems. For some reason the "Vendor" string is being correctly sent to the external application however the "qty_edit" window is not receiving the data. When running this program I can see that the cursor has moved to the correct window but no data was sent. The only difference between these 2 fields in the application is that the "VendorID" window is expecting text but the "qty_edit" window is expecting a number. Is this the reason why the number is not being received?

My second problem relates to the next window that I am trying to write to. In order to enter text into the next window "PartID" I need to send a Tab keystroke to move across from the "qty_edit" window to the "PartID" window. What is the best way for me to move across to this window? I cannot see the location of this window in Spy++. It needs to be activated by a Tab keystroke.

Comment: Probably depends on how the target app is implemented. Without that knowledge, one could only guess. Perhaps worth pointing out that the supported way to automate programs is UIAutomation.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan. Without relevant information about target app, it would be really difficult.

Comment: Without seeing the app you are calling it is tough. You say "'Click Button to open Quantity field" in the code comments: is the "qty_edit" window actually visible at that time, or does it appear once the button is clicked? Could it be that you need to set the handle for "qty_edit" after you have sent the WM_CLICK message?  I assume you have checked that "qty_edit" is not NULL (or 0)? For the 2nd problem, maybe look at GetNextDlgTabItem in the Win32 API?

Comment: I found that there was a sequence issue with my code. The qty_edit window is not visible until the previous step BM_CLICK of the Open_Line button is complete. Therefore I moved the definition for qty_edit down to occur after the SendMessage Open_Line statement and it now works fine.

Answer (score -3):

I think you've made it a lot more complicated than necessary.
This should work (or something similar)

```
AppActivate ("Purchase Order Entry - Infor ERP VISUAL Enterprise - LIVE")
SendKeys Vendor & "{TAB}" & qty
AppActivate (Application.Caption)
```

Comment: The second call to `AppActivate` will fail.

Comment: The second AppActivate is used to reactivate the Excel window, there is no reason why it should fail, unless it has to wait for the other window to finish processing the sending; if so, you can edit

--  
SendKeys Vendor & "{TAB}" & qty, True 'waits until the keys are processed  --
PS: your downvote (if it was you) is not very polite.

Comment: I have tried the simplified method recommended by Zer0Kelvin and it works most of the time,. The issue is that the sendkeys methods seems to be unreliable when sending text. There can be typos in the the text that make this not an option. Not all of the time but enough to be a problem. If it was reliable it would be much better.

Comment: It is strange because according to Microsoft "SendKeys: Send to the active window one or more keystrokes, as if these had been entered via the keyboard".
The problem may not be sending the text, but the way the target application processes what it receives; is the error random?
You can try using Application.SendKeys instead of SendKeys, which inserts characters into the keyboard buffer.
If there are long sequences of characters try breaking them into smaller sequences.